# how do I resize the image shown by st.image

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I have the following code:

```
bottom_image = st.file_uploader('', type='jpg', key=6)
if bottom_image is not None:
    st.image(bottom_image)
```

the problem I run into is some of the images are very large and I want to be able to size them to a fixed size.

Not sure if this makes a difference or not, but the file_uploader is in a column.

I looked at creating a thumbnail but I could not figure that out.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the width parameter.

```
st.image(bottom_image, width=400)
```

Or you can use the Pillow lib to manipulate the width and height.

```
from PIL import Image

bottom_image = st.file_uploader('', type='jpg', key=6)
if bottom_image is not None:
    image = Image.open(bottom_image)
    new_image = image.resize((600, 400))
    st.image(new_image)
```